# how to add to STROTIME

Tags: php, time

Hi All I have the following in PHP in STROTIME, I am getting an integer value from a DB in minutes and want to add this to the STROTIME.

```
$to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:42:00");
```

how would I simply add 60 minutes to to time?

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp is in seconds so just multiply the minutes by 60 seconds and add it:

```
$from_db = 60;

$to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:42:00") + ($from_db * 60);
```

But to be safe across daylight/summer time etc:

```
$to_time = strtotime("+$from_db minutes", strtotime("2008-12-13 10:42:00"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime:add](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

```
$db_val = 60 ;
$date = new DateTime('2008-12-13 10:42:00');
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$db_val.'M'));
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime::modify():

```php
$dt = new DateTime('2008-12-13 10:42:00');
$dt->modify('+60 minutes');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

or just add 60 minutes to your `$to_time` variable:

```
$to_time += 60  * 60;
//          min * sec
```